# Want to show relevent menu item onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following code in my menu . I want to show `"ts-dropdown"` when `"nav-menu a"` is clicked . I want to show relevent menu on `"ts-dropdown"`.How can i do that with javascript or jquery .

**Note:** It is for mobile devices

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul class="ts-dropdown" id="ts-drop1">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home Basic</a></li>
            <li><a href="home-advanced.php">Home Advanced</a></li>
            <li><a href="home-corporate.php">Home Corporate</a></li>
            <li><a href="home-Business.php">Home Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="home-commerce.php">Home E-Commerce</a></li>
            <li><a href="home-onepage.php">Home One Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pages</a>
        <ul class="ts-dropdown" id="ts-drop1">
            <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="404.php">404</a></li>
            <li><a href="pricing.php">pricing</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
```

Comment: What exactly u mean? do you want to show the selected menu as active?? if so just add css class "active" to the selected menu

Comment: @Nayana_Das When i click on home  it will show pages related to home... such like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$(".nav-menu > li > a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the click from following the link
    $(this).parent().find(".ts-dropdown").show(); // Display the .ts-dropdown under the link that was clicked
});
```

### Update

Show clicked menu and hide the rest:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$(".nav-menu > li > a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the click from following the link
    $(".nav-menu .ts-dropdown").hide(); // Hide all menus
    $(this).parent().find(".ts-dropdown").toggle(); // Display the .ts-dropdown under the link that was clicked
});
});
```

Toggle clicked menu and hide the rest:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$(".nav-menu > li > a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the click from following the link
    $showObj = $(this).parent().find(".ts-dropdown");
    $(".nav-menu .ts-dropdown").each(function() {
        if ($showObj.get(0) === $(this).get(0)) {
            $(this).toggle();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: could u plz gimme a jsfiddle??

Comment: I see, it wasn't working because I needed to add .parent() before the find. Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6evz5svt/

Comment: and menu item must be hidden when another menu item is clicked

Answer (score 0):

So If i did not get you wrong, I would use bootstrap's dropdown menu system before Javascript.  Take a look at this 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Otherwise if you really want to use JS.
First change that link to be a button

```
 .ts-dropdown{
   display: none;
  }
```

Jquery:

```
$(".nav-menu button").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".ts-dropdown").css("display", "inline");
  }
```

would partially solve your problem. If you want to add a little animation that is something else

Comment: Wouldn't that display all of the .ts-dropdown, not just the one under the link that was clicked?

Comment: I think you need to also prevent the default action of the click otherwise it would just follow the link.

Comment: Yeah, your solution is better I think. I would just not make that whole thing a link but a button. That would be much more easier to deal with